# Mysql column as vColumn syntax in sql server

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database

I want to know how to implement this query in `sqlserver`.

**Mysql syntax :**

```
SELECT (COUNT(parent.Cat_Name) - 1) AS depth FROM tbl AS parent
```

What is the same query for microsoft sqlserver? Thanks.

**Edit:**

Error while I'm running the query in `sql-server` is :

```
Error Number: 42000

[Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL Server]Column 'category.Cat_ID' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

SELECT node.Cat_ID, node.Cat_Name, (COUNT(parent.Cat_Name) - 1) AS depth FROM category AS node, category AS parent WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt AND node.IsActive = 1 GROUP BY node.Cat_Name ORDER BY node.lft

Filename: C:\EasyPHP-DevServer-14.1VC9\data\localweb\timit\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330
```

Whole entire query is:

```
SELECT node.Cat_ID, node.Cat_Name, (COUNT(parent.Cat_Name) - 1) AS depth
FROM category AS node,
category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
AND node.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY node.Cat_Name
ORDER BY node.lft"
```

Comment: What error occurs when you try to use this query? What have you tried?

Comment: What is the problem you are having? This query should run perfectly fine in sql-server

Comment: Please check edit part.

Comment: Add `node.Cat_ID` in `Group By`  `..GROUP BY node.Cat_ID,node.Cat_Name`

Comment: The general GROUP BY rule is:
If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function.

Comment: Still can't understand `mysql` accepts any other way to use aggragates

Comment: `mysql` allows you tu put just about anything in the `SELECT`, and if it's not in the `GROUP BY`, _something_ will be selected. Really bug-prone, in my opinion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `node.Cat_ID` and `node.lft` to the `GROUP BY` clause:

```
SELECT node.Cat_ID, node.Cat_Name, (COUNT(parent.Cat_Name) - 1) AS depth
FROM category AS node,
category AS parent
WHERE node.lft BETWEEN parent.lft AND parent.rgt
AND node.IsActive = 1
GROUP BY node.Cat_Name, node.Cat_ID, node.lft
ORDER BY node.lft
```

Every column that's used in the `SELECT` or `ORDER BY` part of a query must either be in an aggregate function (like `count`) or in `GROUP BY` - no exceptions permitted, even if, for example, `Cat_ID` is always determined by `Cat_Name`.

Comment: Again , an error occurred. Here is the error: `Column "category.lft" is invalid in the ORDER BY clause because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.`

Comment: Alrighty, so you should add this column to `GROUP BY`. I edited my answer to reflect that.